# Mac OsX (Vagrant 2.2.18) DNS lookup 5s latency

Tags: domain-name-system, php, mac, vagrant

On a regular VM - Vagrant Box (LAMP) on Mac OS, while making a trivial call, there is a 5 Seconds DNS Lookup delay. Is there any reason for it or solution?

Already installed BerlinVagrant/vagrant-dns and added the --natdnshostresolver1 --natdnsproxy1 on settings. The Responses are quicker while calling within 3 seconds. If longer time between, there is a fix 5s timeout.

[image: DNS]